# Adding Multiple Arguments to a Custom Function in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, custom-function

I've searched high and wide for an answer but can't seem to find it. I am trying to alter my custom function that looks up sitemap URL's and the date they were updated to accept a range of inputs.

Here is the current function that works:

```
function sitemap(sitemapUrl, namespace) {
  var array = [];
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sitemapUrl).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var sitemapNameSpace = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");

  var urls = root.getChildren('url', sitemapNameSpace);

  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var loc = urls[i].getChild('loc', sitemapNameSpace).getText();
    var lastmod = urls[i].getChild('lastmod', sitemapNameSpace).getText();
    array.push([loc, lastmod]);
  }

  return array;
}
```

I've tried using Google's example below but doesn't seem to work however I incorporate it into my function. Any ideas?

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(DOUBLE); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    return input * 2;
  }
}
```

Edit: This is how I tried to use Google's example for my function:

```
function sitemaps(sitemapUrl) {

    var array = [];
    var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sitemapUrl).getContentText();
    var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
    var root = document.getRootElement()
    var sitemapNameSpace = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")

    var urls = root.getChildren('url', sitemapNameSpace)

    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
     var loc = urls[i].getChild('loc',sitemapNameSpace).getText();
     var lastmod = urls[i].getChild('lastmod',sitemapNameSpace).getText();
    array.push([loc, lastmod]);
  }
   if (sitemapUrl.map) {            
    return sitemapUrl.map(sitemaps); 
  } else {  
    return array  

}
```

Comment: What do you mean the Google's example does not work? Could you maybe share your sheet? I've tried myself and it works fine. In your main function, you have two inputs variable bu never use the second one, `namespace` why is that?

Comment: I included how I used Google's example within my function above. The second one was editable but I set it in the function so it's actually unnecessary.

Comment: Please provide an example of sheet with a an example of the input you would be having and an example of what do you want your output to look like. I don't know what is the type of output you want to obtain.

Comment: Here is a link to the example for the desired input and output  - Thanks for your help! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15SMEsTbnq_hFsGH_puoSJLuAdT0EYWJXTa7NUB6_kqY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, this made more sense and now I have modified and tested with your data. I have edited my answer to include the use of `flat`, to create a single list.

Comment: That worked perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: Did the answer solved your issue? If so please consider [upvoting/accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so other people having the same issue may benefit it from.

Comment: @Raserhin I tried upvoting but I don't have 15+ reputation according to Stack Overflow. I will come back and upvote when I do. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You are no using the same format as [the Google example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization). As of right now you are checking if the input is an array after actually retrieving the data.

But you using [`fetch`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl) with an array as input could trigger an *Error* and the function may no get to the point where it checks if the `sitemapUrl` can be used with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Also take into account that `map` will call the function in every single element of the array and return an array with a result for each of element. So in your case B3:B6 would call the function for the value at B3, B4, B5 and B6 and return an array of length 4 with the result. For your case in which you want a single list you need to [flattern the array afterwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

I would change your function to be like this:

```
function sitemaps(sitemapUrl) {

    if (sitemapUrl.map) {
        return sitemapUrl.map(sitemaps).flat();
    } else {

        var array = [];
        var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sitemapUrl).getContentText();
        var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
        var root = document.getRootElement()
        var sitemapNameSpace = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")

        var urls = root.getChildren('url', sitemapNameSpace)

        for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            var loc = urls[i].getChild('loc', sitemapNameSpace).getText();
            var lastmod = urls[i].getChild('lastmod', sitemapNameSpace).getText();
            array.push([loc, lastmod]);
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

---

Although what you are doing is fine take into account that it also exists a way to retrieve all the request at the same time ( 
[`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)) but for this specific case you would need to flatten a reshape the input array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried your adjustment but I still can't figure out how to input multiple arguments (i.e. perform the lookup for two different sitemap URL's) and return one list with both results. What should my input look like?